# Android app crashes when webview tries to retrieve string from spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner

My app 2 spinners ,which basically are drop down lists allowing users to select values. Spinner1 has 4options in dropdown and Spinner2 has 5options in dropdown.

If user selects option1 from spinner1 and option1 from spinner2 , a bulleted list [in the HTML webapp version of this app , i use li tags] should be displayed in a webview in a  fragment in rest of the view.The image will make things more clear.
 Now every time i try to select values from both the spinners and click submit ,the application crashes.

I am attaching the code below

This is for Startup Activity-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    private Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    }

    //add items into spinner dynamically
    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Equipment");
        list.add("Indications");
        list.add("Illustration");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    //get the selected dropdown list value
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            /*@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                        "OnClickListener : " + 
                        "\nSpinner 1 : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
                        "\nSpinner 2 : " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/

             @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     WebViewerFragment wvf = (WebViewerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.webviewfrag);
                       if (wvf != null && wvf.getView() != null) { 
                            wvf.updateWebView(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition(), spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());
                       }
                }



        });

    }



}
```

This is the method for webview

```
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class WebViewerFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView mWebView;
    // a two dimensional array representing the data to put in the WebView
     String mData[][]= new String[4][5]; 
     {
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                mData[i][j]="<html><body><h1>Temp1</h1></body></html>";

            }
        }
     }

/*     Toast.makeText(this, mData[i][j],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   
*/     



 /*    int[][] a1 = {
              { 1, 2, 3, },
              { 4, 5, 6, },
            };
   {  {},{}};


  */

/*     String SurgEqui="<html><body><h2>Equipment</h2><ul><li><p>IV catheter :Be certain that IV is in place and flushing easily</p></li></body><html>";
*/           







    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
        return mainView;
    }

    public void updateWebView(int firstSelection, int secondSelection) {
         if (firstSelection == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION || secondSelection == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
              return;  
         } else {
              if (mWebView != null) {
                  mWebView.loadData(mData[firstSelection][secondSelection].replace("+", "%20"), "text/html", "utf-8");
                  // mWebView.loadData(mData[firstSelection][secondSelection], "text/html", null);
                   //wv.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(myString).replace("+", "%20"), "text/html, "utf-8");

              }
         }

    }


}
```

This is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/webviewfrag"
        android:name="android.webkit.WebViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="246dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
       />







    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSubmit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please always post logcat from crash otherwise you simply waste people's time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the logcat with the error. However there are two issues I have noticed:

1. You initialized spinner2 inside addItemsOnSpinner2() and then you call addListenerOnButton() where you have overwritten spinner2. That probably results with NullPointerException
2. You call addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() after calling addListenerOnButton() where you have referenced to spinner1 which is instantieted in addListenerOnButton(). That will also give you nullPointerException.
   To fix it try:

1.Remove:

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

from addListenerOnButton() method.

2.Call addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() before addListenerOnButton():

```
addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
addListenerOnButton();
```

Comment: you have ClassCastException. Have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me. I have tried cleaning the project and still the errors pops up .Do you suggest any steps to resolve this? Just in case -Here is the project file on Skydrive- https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=ECA41FB04BAECC12!214&authkey=!ALlX5iYLf1vpbJ0.